# Why can't I minimize to tray when I launch Bitcoin on startup?

Tags: bitcoin-core, linux, bitcoin-qt-setup

If I set Bitcoin Core to start on system login, the option to "Hide tray icon" and "Minimize to tray" become disabled. On my system (Pop_OS!) This causes bitcoin-qt to be neither on the system tray, nor in the taskbar when I minimize it, and I don't know how to make it show again.

Is there any reason for these options to be disabled?

How can I make it show again in this scenario?

[image: Example of disabled options]

Comment: See "Compatibility" under https://bitcoincore.org/en/releases/0.21.0/ - if you can repeat this under Ubuntu it might be worth reporting to [BitcoinCore](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues) . If unable to reproduce under Ubuntu I'd report it to [Pop_OS](https://system76.com/contact).

Comment: This occurs when Qt (the GUI library Bitcoin Core uses) detects that there is no system tray available. I don't know how you would resolve that, but it is a starting point for further research.